# Video ads crashing on older devices

Tags: ios, facebook-audience-network

I've recently implemented Facebook Audience Network in my app. I noticed that video ads crash on iPhone 5 and iPhone 4s with the following crashlog on Fabric:

[image: crashlog]

I'm somewhat able to reproduce it: Sometimes it crashes simply when displaying the FBMediaView, other times it happens after tapping the video (which should show it in fullscreen). Looking at the crash in Xcode does not reveal any further information.

[image: crash inside xcode]

Clueless what to do to fix this crash. My only solution right now would be to create an Ad Space for affected devices, which doesn't include video ads. Anyone got a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been talking to the Facebook Team on the Developer Forums. After some back and forth (and providing a small sample project) they told me that it will be fixed in the upcoming version of the Audience Network SDK.

> We have a fix ready and it'll be pushed with the next release of the SDK (unfortunately I can't give an estimated time). I'll update you here when it is released.